# How to get array of dates as POST parameter

Tags: php, restler

it looks like it is not possible to have array of dates as a parameter, like:

```
@param array $dates Dates array {@type date} {@from body}
```

Is there any way to make Restler to validate input of array of dates, for example:

```
{
   "dates": ["2013-01-01", "2013-01-02"]
}
```

Right now I am getting: `Class 'date' not found in ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine with the latest in master branch! Just added the code to test it in Type class

Check it out here http://restler3.luracast.com/tests/param/explorer/index.html#!/type/createDates_post